# PFFile url returns url starts with http instead of https

Tags: swift, http, url, heroku, parse-server

I have a parse server on Heroku, when i try to get the PFFile url it returns the url that starts with http instead of https, how can i access the url that starts with https in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variable `publicServerURL` in your index.js (can't

Here's mine:

```
publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
```

You can then easily set it under Heroku's env vars. Or set it as the same value as `serverUrl`